# Jekyll Github Actions pipeline stuck at jekyll build

Tags: github, continuous-integration, jekyll, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I've been working on a pipeline to build and deploy my Jekyll Site via ssh to a webserver. I've found [this GithubAction](https://github.com/victoriadrake/jekyll-cd/blob/master/jekyll-cd.yml) and tried to reproduce it. Here is my `.yml`

```yaml
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name:  Check out master
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          fetch-depth: 1
      - name:  Install Jekyll
        run: |
          sudo gem install bundler jekyll
          sudo bundle install
      - name:  Clean site
        run: |
          if [ -d "docs" ]; then
            rm -rf docs/*
          fi
      - name:  Build site
        run: bundle exec jekyll build -d docs
```

When running my pipeline it gets stuck at the beginning of the  `Build site` step. It was stuck until i manually canceled it after 18min.

[image: Github Action error]

Running the build command locally works. Any idea what the mistake is? Or there better ways to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out various Github Actions i've solved by doing it myself using the [Jekyll Builder Docker Image](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker#readme).

**Care:** you need to pre create `.jekyll-cache` and `_site` because the container does not have the permission to do so. It's a known [issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7591).

```yaml
- name:  Build site
      run: |
        mkdir .jekyll-cache _site
        docker run --rm -v ${{ github.workspace }}:/srv/jekyll jekyll/builder:latest jekyll build
```

After running this command you can do whatever with the `_site` folder. In my case i compressed it and moved it to my server with [appleboys scp-action](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action).